# React native navigation header is not fixed at top for web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I use react native navigation and Expo in my project. Everything works as expected but the header on the web is not fixed. How can I keep it on top even by scrolling the page?

I tried many thing like `cardStyle: { flex: 1 }` in screenOptions but nothing works.

"expo": "^47.0.6",
React native navigation V6

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to see how the UI looks like, also the Component Code to suggest any changes required?

Answer (score 0):

The header can be styled as desirder through Screen -> `options` -> `headerStyle`

There's more info in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#adjusting-header-styles

I set up an Expo Snack with React Navigation v6, with a ScrollView including a few squares, so you can scroll: https://snack.expo.dev/@p-syche/header-styles

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested your snack also with Flatlist and it works. I have nested navigation with drawer and tab buttons and... And it does not work on it.

Comment: I found the problem. I use React native paper DataTable in may page and that was the problem. I set {flex:1} in DataTable and the problem solved

Comment: I'm happy you found your solution :)